# Where to put extjs file?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I came across the extjs class on [GitHub](https://github.com/TKeePeR/extjs-tip-toast) that I would like to use in my application.
Where should I put that file?

I know that file structure in extjs follows some patterns, so for example if the name of my application is MyApp, then I put classes in corresponding folders, like `MyApp.view.myfolder.MyClass`.

However, in this case the usage of class is given as

```
GLC.tip.toast(title, message, options)
```

so I doubt that I should put it in some view folder. On the other hand I tried to copy those two files (glc_tip.js and tip.scss) in the root folder of my application and include in index.html the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="glc_tip.js"/>
```

but it also doesn't work. I got an error that it is not defined.

**UPDATE**

I created folder /ux/tip/ in the application root directory and put files toast.js (renamed glc_tip.js) and tip.scss into it.
After that I modified app.json, so the section with "js" and "css" looks like:

```
"js": [{
    "path": "app.js",
    "bundle": true
},{
    "path": "/ux/tip/toast.js",
    "bundle": true
}],
```

```
"css": [{
    // This entry uses an ant variable that is the calculated value of the generated
    // output css file for the app, defined in .sencha/app/defaults.properties
    "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
    "bundle": true,
    "exclude": ["fashion"]
},{
    "path": "/ux/tip/tip.scss"
}],
```

After that I did `sencha app refresh` and `sencha app build development`, but it still doesn't work. i am getting an error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: GLC is not defined
at constructor.handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to register the third party libs in 'app.json' file. There must be js and css sections. You can put it in '/ux/tip/toast.js' file (create dirs if they do not exist).

**Js files in**

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "${framework.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true
    }
],
```

**CSS files will be registered in**

```
"css": [
    {
        // this entry uses an ant variable that is the calculated
        // value of the generated output css file for the app,
        // defined in .sencha/app/defaults.properties
        "path": "${build.out.css.path}",
        "bundle": true,
        "exclude": ["fashion"]
    }
],
```

And do not forget to rebuild and refresh your project to apply changes.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion. Could you please take a look an tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you have forgotten to rename the class from GLC.. appropriate one. Something like YOUR_PROJECT_NAME.ux.Tip..

Comment: The original class is defined as Ext.define('GLC.tip', {... Could you please confirm if I need to change that definition to Ext.define('MyApp.ux.tip.toast', {...

Comment: Yes something like this.

Comment: Now I am geting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: m.slideIn is not a function

Comment: This lib is implemented for classic toolkit, and you are using modern.. Better to forget about it.

Comment: Thank you, that was very useful. Actually, I am having problems with using standard Ext.Toast, and that is why I wanted to try this one.

Comment: I have seen your post, but could not reproduce the bug.